# python changing the value while doing average

Tags: python

I'm currently getting an average value with a twist.  I'm averaging items but if I see a certain product name, I need to count that value as 3.  I can't make it work.  Below is my code and XML (shortened) file.  Basically if the loop see the Tofus, quantity should be overwritten with 3 and not 9..then get the average.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.ElementTree(file="nwind_medium.xml")

orders = root.findall("./orders")
quantityTotal = 0
for order in orders:
    orderdetails = order.findall("./orderdetails")
    for detail in orderdetails:
        productName = detail.findall("./products/productname")
        quantityNew = detail.findall("./quantity")
        if productName[0].text == "chang" or productName[0].text == "chai" or productName[0].text == "Tofus":
            quantityNew = 3;
        else: 
            quantityTotal += float(quantityNew[0].text)
numberQuantity = len(orders)
```

print "Average number of items an order is", round((quantityTotal / numberQuantity),1)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<nwind> -<orders another="Friday" orderid="10248"> -<customers> <companyname>Vins et alcools Chevalier</companyname> <customerid>VINET</customerid> </customers> -<orderdetails> -<products> <productid>72</productid> <productname>Mozzarella di Giovanni</productname> </products> <unitprice>34.8</unitprice> <quantity>5</quantity> -<suppliers> <supplierid>14</supplierid> <companyname>Formaggi Fortini s.r.l.</companyname> </suppliers> </orderdetails> -<orderdetails> -<products> <productid>11</productid> <productname>Queso Cabrales</productname> </products> <unitprice>14</unitprice> <quantity>12</quantity> -<suppliers> <supplierid>5</supplierid> <companyname>Cooperativa de Quesos 'Las Cabras'</companyname> </suppliers> </orderdetails> -<orderdetails> -<products> <productid>42</productid> <productname>Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee</productname> </products> <unitprice>9.8</unitprice> <quantity>10</quantity> -<suppliers> <supplierid>20</supplierid> <companyname>Leka Trading</companyname> </suppliers> </orderdetails> </orders> -<orders orderid="10249"> -<customers> <companyname>Toms Spezialitaten</companyname> <customerid>TOMSP</customerid> </customers> -<orderdetails> -<products> <productid>14</productid> <productname>Tofus</productname> </products> <unitprice>18.6</unitprice> <quantity>9</quantity> -<suppliers> <supplierid>6</supplierid> <companyname>Mayumi's</companyname> </suppliers> </orderdetails> -<orderdetails> -<products> <productid>51</productid> <productname>Manjimup Dried Apples</productname> </products> <unitprice>42.4</unitprice> <quantity>40</quantity> -<suppliers> <supplierid>24</supplierid> <companyname>G'day, Mate</companyname> </suppliers> </orderdetails> </orders> -<orders orderid="10250"> -<customers> <companyname>Hanari Carnes</companyname> <customerid>HANAR</customerid> </customers> -<orderdetails> -<products> <productid>65</productid> <productname>Louisiana Fiery Hot Pepper Sauce</productname> </products> <unitprice>16.8</unitprice> <quantity>15</quantity> -<suppliers> <supplierid>2</supplierid> <companyname>New Orleans Cajun Delights</companyname> </suppliers> </orderdetails> -<orderdetails> -<products> <productid>41</productid> <productname>Jack's New England Clam Chowder</productname> </products> <unitprice>7.7</unitprice> <quantity>10</quantity> -<suppliers> <supplierid>19</supplierid> <companyname>New England Seafood Cannery</companyname> </suppliers> </orderdetails> -<orderdetails> -<products> <productid>51</productid> <productname>Manjimup Dried Apples</productname> </products> <unitprice>42.4</unitprice> <quantity>35</quantity> -<suppliers> <supplierid>24</supplierid> <companyname>G'day, Mate</companyname> </suppliers> </orderdetails> </orders> </nwind>
```

Comment: You're setting `quantityNew = 3` but then summing `quantityNew[0].text` - does that even work ?

Comment: I'd do `if productName[0].text == "chang" or ... : _quantity = 3; else: _quantity = float(quantityNew[0].text); quantityTotal += _quantity`

Comment: @AdamSmith It seems that the value was change to zero and not 3.  I got an output of 42.3.  It should be 43.3.  Thanks

Comment: @user_new_in_python I'm 100% certain that the code you posted either does not run or will never enter the `if` block. If your code is different, I can't comment, but the code you posted here WILL throw a `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` if any `productName[0].text` matches `"chang", "chai", or "Tofus"`

Comment: @AdamSmith Sorry about that... Yeah I know that the one I posted will show up an error because I'm not sure on how to proceed with the else statement.  That's why I left it blank to get a suggestion on what to put.  I was not clear on my post.

Comment: I updated the code... It seems that it's changing the value to zero and not 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.ElementTree(file="nwind_medium.xml")

orders = root.findall("./orders")
quantityTotal = 0
for order in orders:
    orderdetails = order.findall("./orderdetails")
    for detail in orderdetails:
        productName = detail.findall("./products/productname")
        quantityNew = detail.findall("./quantity")
        if productName[0].text == "chang" or productName[0].text == "chai" or productName[0].text == "Tofus":
            _quantity = 3
        else:
            _quantity = float(quantityNew[0].text)
        quantityTotal += _quantity
numberQuantity = len(orders)
```

Comment: Thank you.  It works after adding the variable _quantity inside the loop.  Please update the posted answer then I'll accept it as a solution.  Thanks again :)

Comment: @user_new_in_python I don't understand -- my code as written is correct

Comment: @user_new_in_python I never define `quantity`. Did you copy my code incorrectly?